# Does System Restore on Windows affect an Ubuntu installation via Wubi?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, system-restore, wubi

I have Ubuntu 9.10 installed via WUBI within Windows. If I run a System restore, will it remove my Ubuntu installation?

Comment: It may affect the registry settings, but I don't think system restore deletes files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite likely it will attempt to restore boot.ini -- along with the line that lets you boot Wubi.

That's to name *one* thing that might go wrong.

Comment: Depends on the Windows version. Remember that more recent versions have a different boot loader.

Comment: I actually went through with the System Restore. And my Ubuntu installation remains in tact. So I guess that problem's solved.